# FireMonkey - TListBox Enable Drag Drop

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to enable the dragging and dropping for TListBoxItems inside a TListBox in FireMonkey. It seems to drag and drop sometimes, but other times it does not even enter the event handler

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragChange(SourceItem, DestItem: TListBoxItem; var Allow: Boolean);
begin
  SourceItem.Index := DestItem.Index;
end;
```

I have the DragMode as dmManual

```
object ListBox1: TListBox
    Height = 200.000000000000000000
    Position.X = 224.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 144.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Width = 200.000000000000000000
    AllowDrag = True
    Items.Strings = (
      'First'
      'Second'
      'Third'
      'Fourth'
      'Fifth'
      'Sixth')
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    OnDragChange = ListBox1DragChange
  end
```

Comment: You're not setting a return value for Allow, which means it's return value will probably be random.

Comment: @MikeSutton `var` arguments are always initialized by the method caller. If not, it is a bug. So there is no random value at all.

Comment: It seems to work every time if you first select the item (click and then release the left mouse button) and then click the same item and drag/drop. If you don't separate the selection and drag by releasing and then pressing the mouse button, it seems to fail.

Comment: @MikeSutton: `Allow` is initialized in `TCustomListBox.DragChange` (in FMX.ListBox, around line 2933) before `OnDragChange` is called, so it can't be *random*.